# Go out for a beer

Tags: meaning

What does the sentence "We should go out for some beer." mean?

1. We should go somewhere and drink beer there.
2. We should go somewhere, buy some beer and come back.

Maybe both meanings are right? Thanks.

Comment: I'd say it could mean either.

Comment: Usually this is idiomatic and means we should go and socialise together, probably at a pub or bar. It doesn't necessarily mean drinking beer specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say the key word is "some," indicating a supply. As in, we are camping, and we should go out for some beer (to bring back here and drink). If you wanted to invite someone to go to a bar with you, you would say, "Let's go out for a beer." Similarly, you could invite someone to go for "a coffee," i.e., at a café.

Comment: Thanks. I've an additional question. Is any difference between "I’m going for breakfast" and "I’m going for A breakfast"?

Comment: I'm doubtful. *Let's go out for some nachos* or even *let's go out for some pizza* are invitations to restaurants (Mexican and Italian, respectively).

Comment: –1.  It can quite happily mean both versions — the shop, or the bar. The first page of Google results for the `go out for some beer` yields plenty of examples of the latter, e.g. *My buddy just had a bad day, and he wanted to go out for some beer and killer nachos*, and *I wanna go out for a beet tonight… but no one to go with…”.  I’m a hurry, or I’d make this a full answer — hopefully someone else will.

Comment: I don't think I've heard a native English speaker say, "Let's go out for some beer," meaning let's go to a bar and have one or more glasses of beer. You could say "some nachos," because nachos are countable. Pizza is like beer: "Let's go out for pizza." These are just my impressions as a native speaker. Cheers!

Comment: Regarding "I’m going for breakfast" and "I’m going for A breakfast," one would usually say "I'm going for breakfast" to mean I'm going to have my morning meal. When one talks about "a breakfast," it sounds like an event: "The politician attended a breakfast with local dignitaries and made important statements there."